# How to animate the on enter and on leave of an updating Observable's values in an Angular+ template binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, observable

### **[Plnkr:](https://plnkr.co/edit/ka6ewGPo1tgnOjRzYr3R?p=preview)**

https://plnkr.co/edit/ka6ewGPo1tgnOjRzYr3R?p=preview

**I have a subscription that will change overtime:**

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.snapshot.data.remote.subscribe(x => {
      this.obs$ = x[0];
    });
  }
```

**I have a template `work-post.component.html` that showcases these changes:**

```
  <h1>{{obs$.title}}</h1>
  <p>
    {{obs$.paragraph}}
  </p>
```

### **Question:**

When `obs$` gets each next/new value, Is it possible to animate the enter and leave animations of these values.  Can `obs$.title obs$.paragraph` bindings have a "crossfade" e.g. fade out old text, fade in the new text on change? if so, how could I implement this animation inside of my component and template:

component:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'work-post',
  templateUrl: 'work-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['work-post.component.scss'],
})
export class WorkPostComponent implements OnInit{
  public obs$;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.snapshot.data.remote.subscribe(x => {
      this.obs$ = x[0];
    });
  }

}
```

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFiIifkBKT8) of how the UI currently looks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want to apply X method (animations) when your `obs$` changes value. So, in my opinion, you need a listener.

For this, I would go for `DoCheck`.

**In component:**

```
import { Component, DoCheck, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class MyClass implements OnInit, DoCheck {

ngDoCheck() {
    if(this.obs$ !== 'whateverValue') {
      // Apply an animation because this.obs$ changed
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html

**Update 1:**

I suggest that you store an initial version of `this.obs$` in, for example, `this.obs_initial`.

And inside the logic in the listener you compare both, if `this.obs$` is different from its previous value (`this.obs_initial`) then means that `this.obs$` changed and therefore we trigger X animation.

Comment: Is there any way to do this declaratively and Using the @angular/animation library?

Comment: You could create a method for each *animation* that you know you will trigger when eventually `this.obs$` changes its value. And that you can do it with `@angular/animation`. And then using `DoCheck` you constantly listen and as soon as you detect that `this.obs$` changes you trigger the method that you created that contains the library's animation or animations.

Comment: If I was to wrap the content into their own component and @Input the data in to component. Use that Input to trigger to animate, would that be a better approach?

Comment: Then you could use shared service to communicate constantly between main component and the rest of small components and still use the listener to detect changes in the small components, no?

Comment: Let me know what you decide, tomorrow at the office I will have another look! ;)